# Dropdown on div element with bootstrap-vue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm realy not fan of bootstrap-vue... and i have some problem is it possible to create something like this?

```
<div class="dropdown open">
    <div data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">some text</div> 
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="left_side" class="col-lg-6">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="aaa">AAA</label> 
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="bbb">BBB</label>
            </div> 
            <div id="right_side" class="col-lg-6">some text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was trying many options but `<b-dropdown>` always create `<button>` tag

Comment: Why not just style the button the way that you want? You can add a `class` to it and style it however

Comment: If Vue-Bootstrap does not provide the feature you need... Why don't you just use the code you pasted in your question? :)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I'm trying to restyle the button itself but find it annoying because of the button styles applied by the btn and btn-primary classes that automatically get applied, even if you change the tag to a.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe provide your example usage of bootstrap-vue. The dropdown component has sub components for DD items and DD item buttons. https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Elements that are not `button` or `a` are not accessibility friendly (they do not have the correct semantic meanings to screen reader users).

You should always use semantic elements where possible, and apply styling to make them appear as you need.

Why use a `div` which does not convey "clickable", when `button` always conveys that it is a clickable element that has the same click and keyboard behaviour expected by screen reader users or keyboard only users.

BootstarpVue provides various props for `b-dropdown` to control styles on the trigger buttons (or anchor tags when in a navbar).

Docs are available at https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/dropdown